# Butterworth filter example with SPUC

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I've been looking into signal processing libraries for C++, and [SPUC](http://spuc.sourceforge.net/) seems to be one of the most commonly mentioned libraries. However, I have found very few examples on the web of how one might use SPUC in a program.

Could someone familiar with this library post a simple example of how one would use a Butterworth filter?